# how to change the background color size in a button?

Tags: css, background-color

I designed some button like this: 
[image]

however I couldn't change the size of background-color:  #428bca as my design in css. Is any way I can change the size of background color in CSS not using background-image?

Please see the simple example here:

```
 <button class="btn-modify">
    Primary
    </button>

    .btn-modify {
     width: 286px;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color:  #428bca;
     }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zichenma/f8hjm0Lc/

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please provide the code that you have used

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the markup provided does not match the image or the stated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if assumed right then you want this i.e half background is of another color or another half of is another color .. and you can achieve with this code

```
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(#0e88be, #0e88be 49.9%, #1e90ff 50.1%, #1e90ff 100%);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what I need